# Starting Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, filepath, autoloader

I have seen a lot of similar tutorials and questions to my problem, but none seem to cover what is going on here. Being new to Laravel I'm having some difficulty with the index.php. It looks like the __DIR__ ."path/here" doesn't accept ../ like one would expect. It's appending to the file path instead of moving up directories. As can be seen below in the warning/error:

```
Warning: require(/home/user1/public_html/blog/../vendor/autoload.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/user1/public_htm/blog/index.php on line 27

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
'/home/user/public_html/blog/../vendor/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') 
in /home/user1/public_html/blog/index.php on line 27
```

I have also tried this, but I don't think that's the problem,

```
$app->bind('path.public', function ()
{
    return base_path() . '/public_html';
});
```

It's the directory path that's wrong, but I can't get the right path. Typically I would just ../ as many times as needed, but that won't work here. Any thoughts on how to get my path changed to /home/user1/vendor/autoload.php instead of what it is in the warning and error? Spent too many hours on this now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

```
composer install -d /home/user1/
```

Is needed to run globally installed composer. Both install and update have been run and no change was made. The dependencies are not an issue it would seem. At least not with the paths needing a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to make **public folder** of your Laravel project as **ROOT** if you are trying to run on server

Or

you need to add **.htaccess file** in your **ROOT** directory with below syntax.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also run below command from your server if allowed

```
composer update
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that .htaccess throws a 500 error and my project accepts public_html just fine. The page loads up it's just blank, probably because the auto loader isn't getting used.

Comment: Can you tell me which **Laravel version** you are using and which **PHP version** on server?

Comment: PHP 7.1.10 and Laravel 5.5

Comment: Please give 755 permission to your vendor folder

Comment: One step ahead of you, already done. I think it’s the file path that’s wrong. Do you know how to change it? It’s looking for the auto loader in the wrong spot and I don’t know how to adjust that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe composer install run missing.

Just run the following command, it will automatically install necessary dependencies:

**composer install**

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this command `composer install`
2. Then `composer update`
3. Then `composer dump-autoload`

Finally, Restart server and try again.

Comment: What do you do when you install composer globally, and it won't let you update? I can't run install/update/etc in the directory my app is, but I installed Laravel and started the project just fine yesterday.